# Issues with Devexpress Grid

Tags: devexpress

I am using a devexpress grid with editform template. When I click on the edit button, this edit form is displayed. The edit form has an Update and Cancel button at the bottom of the form. I want to set the focus on the cancel button when this edit form is opened. Is it possible to set the focus on either update/cancel buttons when this edit form is opened?

Answer (score 0):

You can use template for Edit Form and Specify The TabIndex Property For The Buttons :

I have attached sample example for your reference.

If any question, feel free to ask.

```
 <Templates>
                                        <EditForm>
                                            <table style="width: 100%">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="right">
                                                        <dx:ContentControl ID="ContentControl" runat="server" SupportsDisabledAttribute="True">
                                                            <dx:ASPxGridViewTemplateReplacement runat="server" ID="Editors" ReplacementType="EditFormEditors" />
                                                        </dx:ContentControl>
                                                        <table style="width: 100%;">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td align="right" style="padding-right: 20px">
                                                                    <table>
                                                                        <tr>                                                                    
                                                                            <td>
                                                                                <dx:ASPxButton ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" CssFilePath="~/App_Themes/Office2010Blue/{0}/styles.css" TabIndex="0"
                                                                                    AccessKey="S" AutoPostBack="False" Text="Update" Width="60px" ClientSideEvents-Click='<%# "function(s, e) { " + Container.UpdateAction + " }" %>'
                                                                                    CssPostfix="Office2010Blue" SpriteCssFilePath="~/App_Themes/Office2010Blue/{0}/sprite.css" >                                                                                
                                                                                </dx:ASPxButton>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                            <td>
                                                                                <dx:ASPxButton ID="btnCancel" runat="server" CssFilePath="~/App_Themes/Office2010Blue/{0}/styles.css" TabIndex="1"
                                                                                    AutoPostBack="False" Text="Cancel" Width="60px" ClientSideEvents-Click='<%# "function(s, e) { " + Container.CancelAction + " }" %>'
                                                                                    CssPostfix="Office2010Blue" SpriteCssFilePath="~/App_Themes/Office2010Blue/{0}/sprite.css">
                                                                                </dx:ASPxButton>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </EditForm>
                                    </Templates>
```

Answer (score 0):

please use the approach described in the ASPxGridView inline editing "tab order" report.

> http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q218510

If you place your own editors in the EditForm template, set the TabIndex property of each editor according to your requirements.